# Running container in ECS Fargate as non-root user throws EACCES error

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, alpine-linux

I have an ECS Fargate service configured. Updating the Dockerfile to use a non-root user, the following error was logged to CloudWatch:

```
npm ERR! path /opt/app/package.json
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/opt/app/package.json'
```

When running the container as the default root user, I do not have any issues.

The non-root Dockerfile (below) works locally. (OS: Pop!_OS 18.10;
Docker 18.09.6)

**Root-user Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:10.16-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app

WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY src/package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY src .

RUN npm run spec:build

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**Non-root Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10.16-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app

WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY src/package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY src .

RUN npm run spec:build \
  && chown -R node: ./**/*

USER node

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```